# MySQL query to show results

Tags: mysql

My query is...

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.FeeName,
    SUM(tbl1.FeeAmount) AS TotAmt
FROM 
    tbl1
WHERE
    tbl1.DateTaken BETWEEN '2017-06-02' AND '2017-06-06'
GROUP BY
    tbl1.FeeId
```

The output is...

[image: Fee]

The table has other Fees that are not taken (transaction) between the above dates therefore not showing in the `query` result.

I want to show those FeeNames and the value should be **0**. Just like below (The yellow colored results).

[image: Fee1]

What should I do ?

Comment: do you have a separate "fees" table (as would be appropriate for a normalised database). I think if you joined against that, you could get all the fees in there, even the zero ones. Might need to be a left join. Haven't got access to a DBMS to test that right now.

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry. What is that ? Your high thought comment is like a `Tangent` for my **Small Head**.

Comment: @Raj Strawberry is just saying the question might be easier for more people to answer if you give complete information for the question, in this case the underlying data structure etc would have been useful in order to allow people to reproduce the issue. I see someone has come up with something, but there are a lot of unanswered questions on the site where the OP hasn't given sufficient detail.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for the information. I think, I've provided sufficient detail. If not, anybody can tell me to provide it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this :** this will only perform sum operations of fees which are in given date range, for remaining fees this will put 0

```
SELECT 
tbl1.FeeName,
SUM(CASE WHEN tbl1.DateTaken BETWEEN '2017-06-02' AND '2017-06-06' 
         THEN tbl1.FeeAmount
         ELSE 0
    END) AS TotAmt
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY  tbl1.FeeId
```